# Eclipse - Maven dependency is being ignored

Tags: java, maven, pmml

**I have a problem with adding maven dependencies to eclipse**.

What should be OK:

- pom.xml already contains all the dependencies and compilation and running tests using maven finished with success
- all the source folders were recognized by eclipse
- eclipse has Maven plugin and project is managed as maven project (see figure below)
- pom.xml has maven-compiler-plugin, so the eclipse should know it is a maven project

  ```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

Issue:

- eclipse does not resolve dependencies defined in pom.xml (guava, juint and other libraries are in pom.xml but not in eclipse class path)
- any right click > Maven > Update project has no any effect (see figure below)
- I noticed that libraries does not contain any Maven Managed Dependencies - by adding as described below has no any effect

[image]

**My attempt to add Maven Managed Dependencies to Eclipse manually**

1) Add library

[image]

[image]

[image]

1)
This attempt has no any effect and "Java Library Path" remains the same even after this action.

2)
Command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Fails with

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pmml-model: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jpmml:pmml-model:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jpmml:pmml-agent:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT, org.jpmml:pmml-schema:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.jpmml:pmml-agent:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT in sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The jar does not exist in the desired version on the [server](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) your maven script is referencing. The most recent version is 1.2.9. The snapshot version is not present. You should reference

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
  <artifactId>pmml-model</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

in your pom.xml.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below jars are not present in your remote repo.

```
org.jpmml:pmml-agent:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT, 
org.jpmml:pmml-schema:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

Open the url https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots in your browser to see the available snapshots/

Comment: I see that other related project has generated snapshot builds at: jpmml-model\pmml-agent\target\pmml-agent-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar, is there any simple way how to add the project jpmml-model to my repository?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are trying to set up a project that makes use of the JPMML-Evaluator library. In that case, you should only depend on the latest stable `org.jpmml:pmml-evaluator` dependency (which is version 1.2.13 at the moment). In other words, don't try to manage the associated `org.jpmml:pmml-model`, `org.jpmml:pmml-schema` dependencies manually.

You could base your work on the [JPMML-Evaluator-Bootstrap](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-bootstrap) project instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is under AGPL license which cannot be used for my purpose